# How do i fill this boundary of a cat with white colour using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have already tried `imfill(img)` but that doesn't work at all.
 
I have noticed that **imfill** works for this purpose only for images in which the object's boundary is complete and not broken like the image i am taking .

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Actually your cat already is filled. `imread` returns a `500x368 uint8`. Outside the contour value = `0` (black), contour value = `255` (white) and the area inside the cat value = `1` (almost black). So you can do something like `im( im == 1 ) = 255;`. But another thought was also like @Piglet's to add a helper line or border around the image which can later be removed again.

Comment: The example you have added is a direct contradiction to what you're actually looking for.  You have images that have "broken lines", yet the example you have provided has a completely connected contour.  **Show us a real example**.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular image do the following:

Prepend a white row to the image to close the contour.
Fill the contour.
Remove the helper row.

Anything else requires more information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab documentation states that *"a hole is a set of background pixels that cannot be reached by filling in the background from the edge of the image"*. In this case any pixel can be reached from the edge because its boundary is not complete. Therefore, technically there is no hole in the image you posted.